# Как из массива изображений выбрать первое и вывести его?

Tags: php

Есть запись у которой несколько изображений в виде слайдера. Добавляю как массив, все ок, добавляется. Как вывести из всего этого массива первое изображение которое добавилось в бд таблицу? Мне нужно на отдельной странице вывести все записи с главной фотографией. Главная фотография я выбрал это та которая 1-я добавилась в бд.

Например, таблица images

```html
id | id_post | name_images | created_at
1 | 45 | images1.jpg | 16.07.2021
2 | 45 | images2.jpg | 16.07.2021
```

В таблице images есть 2 фотки у записи с id 45

Как вывести первую фотку которая добавилась с бд? В данном случае с id 1 так как он раньше добавился. Нужно как то вывести массив всех этих фоток и узнать первую, но я не догоняю как можно сделать. Можете подсказать?

Comment: `order by id` первую из базы - limit 1, первую из массива $arr[0]

Answer (score -1):

```
Картинка кнопка (более сложный вариант), но разобраться можно;  
 $conn1 = new mysqli('ip', 'login', '****', 'namebd');
    // Check connection
    if ($conn1->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn1->connect_error);
    } 
    
     mysqli_set_charset($conn1,"utf8");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id=0";
    $result = $conn1->query($query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    //print_r($row)."<br>\n";
    $arr[]=$row['name_images'];
    
    $derect="C:\\images\\".$arr[0];
    
    
    
    $adres='http://localhost/index1.php';
    $error='Нажмите и ожидайте';
    $info='Описание картинки';
    $names='Название';
    echo "<button class='navbar-toggler collapsed' style='width:120x;height:180px' onclick='cansel()' type='submit' name='mysel' value="1"><small><small>$info<br>$names</small></small><pre></pre><img src=".$derect." width='120' height='120' align='middle' alt=".$info." title=".str_replace(' ','',$info)."></button>";
    echo "<script>function cansel(){var txt; var r=confirm('".$error."'); if(r == false){document.open('index1.php'); }} </script>";
    
    }
```

Comment: Это очень странный ответ, выглядит как будто его сделали из нескольких не связанных между собой кусков кода